# Cannot get Marionette example code to run on Python + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox-marionette

so unfortunately `Webdriver` doesn't work anymore with Firefox 47+, so I was looking into switching to `Marionette`.

I've been following the instruction [on this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver)

Unfortunately the example code below doesn't run:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX

caps["marionette"] = True

caps["binary"] = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe"

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps)
```

I get the following error :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\Programming\repos\locreqmonkey\.git\LRT_Monkey\LRT_Monkey.py", line 21, in <module>
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps)
      File "C:\Users\rhonore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 60, in __init__
        self.service.start()
      File "C:\Users\rhonore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\service.py", line 59, in start
        self.log_file = file("geckodriver.log", "w")
    NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

Pretty sure this is something dumb I'm missing out but I can't figure what it is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the [Marionette executable as well](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver#Setting_up_the_Marionette_executable).
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Place it somewhere in your path.

**Updated:**

It's working for me on Linux with Firefox 47.

Mozilla recommends to use a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/), have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks, I have though... And I also placed the path to its folder in my PATH variable as instructed.

Comment: Are you sure your problem isn't in the python script/modules? Have your tried python2 or python3?

Comment: Python 3.5.0 here. I don't know, I think Selenium is up-to-date, but I will try to reinstall it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As mentioned below my selenium was outdated :/

Answer (score 0):

Current version of Firefox doesn't work with `selenium webdriver`. Why you are not trying to install earlier version of Firefox.

Firefox 47.0 works fine for me. You can download it from [Firefox FTP](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/47.0/)

You can try any other older version of Firefox from [here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/)

**Note:** Don't forget to turn off Firefox auto update.

Comment: Hey, downgrading is not an option (corporate environment)

Comment: Firefox 47 does work here with selenium, no problems on Linux with mentioned settings. `(caps["marionette"] = True)`

Comment: Ah, I should have mentioned I'm on windows 10 64 bits. Maybe comes from that.

Comment: I needed to upgrade Selenium. I still don't understand how to make Marionette work, but Webdriver is working again, although it keeps popping up firstrun page at the beginning of each script, but that's not really a big issue.